# Using a coroutine inside a Transform.map function

Tags: android, kotlin, transformation, kotlin-coroutines

Well here is a tricky one. 
I have a query from my Room DB. The result is a Relational POJO

```
class MessageWithMsgQueueAccount {

    @Embedded
    var message: MessageDto? = null

    @Relation(parentColumn = "clientMessageId", entityColumn = "clientMessageId", entity = MessageQueueDto::class)
    var messageQueueList: List<MsgQueueAccount> = ArrayList()


}
```

So when i get that i apply a Transformation to this object so i can create another one that has only the information that i want.

```
fun toContactMessageChatItem(item: MessageWithMsgQueueAccount?, accountDto: AccountDto): MessageChatItem {

            item?.message?.let {
                // Procedure for creating the fields that i want

                val isQuoted = it.quotemsgid > 0L
                if (isQuoted) {
                    // Fetch quoted message body
                }
                return MessageChatItem(.....)
            } ?: run {
                return MessageChatItem(..........)
            }
    }
```

Since this is a chat, one field that i want to setup is a quoted message body. What i have as "input" is the messageId of the message that is being quoted. So that means that i have to make a query to my Room DB again inside the transform function.
The way i did it is this

```
val isQuoted = it.quotemsgid > 0L
var quotedBody = ""
if (isQuoted) {
   // Fetch quoted message body
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val quotedMessage = messagesRepository.getMessageByMessageId(it.quotemsgid)
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      quotedBody = quotedMessage.body
   }
}
}
```

There no specific question but is there any better way to do something like this, meaning querying the DB  inside a Transformation function. Is there a way that this would create a synchronize problem to my elements or something?

Comment: Not the problem you ask about, but you should `launch` without arguments and use `withContext(IO)` around the DB call. And more to the point, there is no way to call suspendable code without launching a coroutine.

Comment: I believe Room automatically offloads to a background Thread when using suspend functions as part of the DAO.

Comment: I think it depends on how you declare the annotated function. It should be declared as `suspend fun` and then you don't need `withContext(IO)`.

Comment: That is correct. When you declare your DAO function as a suspend function, it will automatically be moved to a background Thread.